# AndEngine Library Can't Reference Physics

Tags: android, eclipse, box2d, andengine

I just installed AndEngine on Eclipse and when I use the following code it won't reference some of the classes. I imported everything from andengine and it still will not find some of it.  Body and FixedStepPhysicsWorld will not get referenced.

```
import org.andengine.*;


public class RagdollActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener, IOnSceneTouchListener {

    // ====================================================
    // CONSTANTS
    // ====================================================
    public static int cameraWidth = 800;
    public static int cameraHeight = 480;

    // ====================================================
    // VARIABLES
    // ====================================================
    public Scene mScene;
    public *FixedStepPhysicsWorld* mPhysicsWorld;
    public *Body* groundWallBody;
    public *Body* roofWallBody;
    public *Body* leftWallBody;
    public *Body* rightWallBody;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this, however Box2d is not directly supported in the AndEngine Library. It is another library which can be obtained from:

[Nicolas Gramlich's (the creator of AndEngine) GitHub Page](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension)

You have to add this library in Eclipse as well in order to use Box2D physics in your AndEngine game.